# How to prevent access to wp-admin for certain user roles?

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles

I did try using the plugin Front End Users but this clashes with something as it prevents access to some front end pages.  So I need to manually just set it so that anyone who isn't one of two usernames (or roles) can't access wp-admin.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Plugin

It's basically just a user capability check, followed by a redirect in an exit call. It then redirects to the site the request came from.

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#66093) »kaiser« Deny Admin-UI access for certain roles */


function wpse66093_no_admin_access()
{
    // Do not run if the user is logged in and trying to log out
    // This might need one or two more checks.
    // Especially if you have custom login/logout/reset password/etc rules and routes set up.
    if ( 
        ! is_admin()
        || (
            is_user_logged_in()
            && isset( $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) AND 'wp-login.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow']
        )
    ) {
        return;
    }

    $redirect = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : home_url( '/' );
    if ( 
        current_user_can( 'CAPABILITY_NAME_HERE' )
        OR current_user_can( 'CAPABILITY_NAME_HERE' )
    )
        exit( wp_redirect( $redirect ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse66093_no_admin_access', 100 );
```

Keep in mind that should only work with defaults (see comments in code). Custom login, logout, register, password reset logic might breaks this.

**Roles vs. Capabilities:** As role names can change and as roles are just groups of capabilities, it's best to check against a capability, not a role name. You can find a list of built in roles and capabilities [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capability-vs-role-table). Just look at what the most restrictive access is and search for a matching capability. Then assign it above. That's easier to maintain, in case a role name changes. Yes, you can use a role name as well, which will work in WordPress, but it's a concept that will bring along a hard to track down bug when a role name changes.

*Note:* Do not think about roles in a hierarchical manner. Think about the accountant whose email address you enter in some SaaS backend to receive the invoice. Most developers will not have access to billing details and neither will the accountant have access to deployment settings or security credentials. They have differently named roles with equally "high" capabilities, but for completely different parts. Keep this example in mind, when you write capability checks or add custom capabilities to a system.

Comment: so I put this at the top of my functions.php file?

Comment: Either _somewhere_ in your functions.php, or in your plugin or mu-plugins folder. As this isn't something about displaying stuff, it belongs _imho_ in a plugin, hence the plugin header. This has the benfit that this functionality doesn't get lost, when you're changing your theme. Just change the user role names, upload it and you're done.

Comment: It doesn't work.  I changed the user role names to my two roles than can access it.  Then I changed it to a capability e.g. `Add users` and I am still able to access the backend as another user role

Comment: @Nicola There's a **huge difference** between a label in the UI (for e.g.: "Add users") and a real [Role or Capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) - in your case `add_users`.

Comment: ok thanks, I tried the above code with add_users instead and it still doesn't work...if I log in as a user without that capability, I can then navigate to wp-admin

Comment: @Nicola Have you taken a look at the link about Roles and Capabilities ↑ in the above comment? Please make sure, that the user _really_ doesn't have that capability.

Comment: Hey, they definitely don't have that ability.  I have just put the code in my functions.php file as I wasn't sure how to go about adding it as plugin that wp would recognise.  Also, I had an error where `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` was an undefined index, so I put an if isset rule before it

Comment: Ah, ok. Now we know where the problem is: I updated the answer, but should add this as a plugin. It is one, it will be recognized. I just didn't add the complete header (which isn't necessary). You can also run it as mu-plugin (read on codex about it). It's best to keep it as plugin as it then doesn't get lost on theme change.

Comment: ok, can you edit it to make it `if isset` as it is triggering that undefined index 'HTTP_REFERER' again, and I'm not sure of your logic to know if I edit it right.

Comment: hey, it's cool, I just made it redirect to the site homepage.  It works now, thanks!

Comment: Hello again, I have another requirement.  I have a plugin that lets a user update their photo from the front end.  This plugin has to do some backend ajax stuff in order to do that.  

So in the above code, I figure I need to do a check to see if we are on that page.  Howver, as we are in the plugin directory, it doesn't know the current page via wordpress functions so I used `$page = array_shift( explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );`, and then tried to edit the above code to say `if ( current_user_can( 'add_users' ) || $page=="/your-profile/"){` however it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicola Please _always_ add such information to your initial question as edit, not in a comment in here. Second, please go and ask a new question when your topic changed or extended. Thanks.

Comment: It's ok, I sorted it by calling a die($page) realised the plugin was only being called when clicking on edit profile, at which point `$page="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"`.  Sorted now.

Comment: ok, sorry about that

Comment: WordPress will likely start triggering a `_doing_it_wrong()` when checking a role name as a capacity in `current_user_can()`. See [38653](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38653)

Comment: Nice, however users are unable to log out because of this action.

Comment: Remember to check for `defined('DOING_AJAX')` if you have AJAX calls in frontend, or they will be blocked!

Answer (score 7):

Just revisited that answer as it wasn't updated in a long time. Year is 2021.

The accepted answer is checking whether the current page is a `wp-login.php` page **OR** an admin page **WHILE** using an `admin_init` hook, this is nonsense.

[`admin_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/) fires as an admin screen or script is being initialized. It does **NOT** just run on user-facing admin screens. It runs on `admin-ajax.php` and `admin-post.php` as well.

In no cases whatsoever will it fire on a `wp-login.php` as it is **NOT** an admin screen. Tho it will indeed fire upon an ajax request, therefore that case should be handle. [`wp_doing_ajax()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_doing_ajax/) determines whether the current request is a WordPress Ajax request.

In the following example I'm using the `delete_posts` user capability to allow `admin`, `editor` and `author` access to the Wordpress backend. Refer to the [Capability vs. Role Table](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#capability-vs-role-table) for a more restrictive approach.

As a reminder here are the default Wordpress roles ([Summary of Roles](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#summary-of-roles)):

> super admin `→` admin `→` editor `→` author `→` contributor `→` subscriber.

With a single site WordPress installation, Administrators are, in effect, Super Admins.

I've chosen to use [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/) instead of blindly redirecting users. `wp_die()` offer some kind of user onboarding as it kills Wordpress execution and displays an HTML page with an error message. The same approach could be done with redirecting users to a 404 page. Anything that explain the situation is better than a blind home page redirect.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_wpadmin_access' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'restrict_wpadmin_access' ) ) {
    function restrict_wpadmin_access() {
        if ( wp_doing_ajax() || current_user_can( 'delete_posts' ) ) {
            return;
        } else {
            header( 'Refresh: 2; ' . esc_url( home_url() ) );
            $args = array(
                'back_link' => true,
            );
            wp_die( 'Restricted access.', 'Error', $args );
        };
    };
};
```

To prevent the default redirection to the `wp-admin.php` upon login I'm using the [`login_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/) hook filter which Filters the login redirect URL. I'm redirecting them to their own profile page using [`get_author_posts_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_author_posts_url/), but you can easily redirect to whatever page you would like. You could also conditionally redirect based on the user role (eg: admin to the admin page, rest to profile), everything is explained on the CODEX page example section.

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'redirect_user_to_profile_on_login', 10, 3 );
if ( ! function_exists( 'redirect_user_to_profile_on_login' ) ) {
    function redirect_user_to_profile_on_login( $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user ) {
        if ( $user && is_object( $user ) && is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
            $redirect_to = esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ) );
        };
        return $redirect_to;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer mentions *User Role*  but actually uses the function for *User Capability*

Here's the solution for *User Roles*

```
 function wpse66094_no_admin_access() {
    $redirect = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : home_url( '/' );
    global $current_user;
    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
    $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);
    if($user_role === 'YOUR_USER_ROLE_HERE'){
        exit( wp_redirect( $redirect ) );
    }
 }

add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse66094_no_admin_access', 100 );
```

Comment: You should be checking against capabilities not roles. As stated in the `current_user_can()` function CODEX page: "`While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results.` @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/#description

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer provided by @kaiser (thank you btw), this is my working code, just in any case someone needs it. It is placed in `functions.php` file.

The condition used is, if the user **can't** `manage_options` or `edit_posts`.

```
function wpse66093_no_admin_access() {
    $redirect = home_url( '/' );
    if ( ! ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) || current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) )
        exit( wp_redirect( $redirect ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse66093_no_admin_access', 100 );
```

Answer (score 0):

With @kaiser's answer I found you'll need to utilize admin_menu hook over admin_init as it fires before the !user_can_access_admin_page() check in wp-admin/includes/menu.php otherwise if the user doesn't have 'read' access to the dashboard they'll just get the 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' page rather than being redirected.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `read` Capability from the Role the user will not be able to access the dashboard.  They will get the following error:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page.
>
> Reason: The current user doesn't have the "read" capability that is
>   required to access the "Dashboard" menu item.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#read

Comment: maybe worth noting that a user with no capabilities can still log in successfully and the admin bar is displayed.