# Close a wordpress blog - keep site as it is but prevent hacks

Tags: security, static-website

Last summer I created a travelling-blog on my webspace to document my journey. Now the journey is over and I won't put any new posts in this blog. I also don't whish to have any new comments.

How can I close the blog (to make in invulnerable to external hacks, even if I don't install any new upgrades) but keep all posts, comments, pictures, etc. as they are?

What I found is

- https://github.com/megumiteam/staticpress (however, although the resulting static page contains all the blogged content, the design is really messed up.)
- https://github.com/aral/wordpress-migration-tools (I couldn't try this one, because it is written in python and I don't know any python.)

<s>Is one of them recommendable?</s>

Is there another way to prevent all interactions with the page, so there's no need to take care about wordpress (or plugin) updates, while still keeping the site secure?

Comment: I don't know if recommendable, but certainly interesting. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: you are welcome - if you like my question feel free to upvote ;)

Comment: I doubt you can find anything bulletproof.

Comment: @brasofilo got your point - maybe you like the question better now (or maybe you even know an answer)?

Comment: If any of those tools generates a quality mirror static site, that's one thing, and covers the "How to close the blog" part of your Q. The other thing is "Is a static site immune to hacks?". And maybe you should research/ask at [webmasters.se]. Unless a more experienced user jumps in and gives a full Answer.

Comment: @brasofilo ok :) I clarified what I mean once more.

Comment: @brasofilo Your comment below should be an answer.

Comment: Marcel, take a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90589/385), as well as on [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66093/how-to-prevent-access-to-wp-admin-for-certain-user-roles/66104#66104).

Comment: Marcel, just to note that: Any answer (incl. my links), only prevent someone from reaching the login form. Better - imo - would be to simply use a `.htaccess`-rule to prevent access to the `wp-login.php`  and similar sites. This as well prevents PHP from even firing up, so it might be (A) the simplest and (B) the most resource efficient solution.

Comment: @kaiser right - one could also lock the whole wp-admin folder like this (or is that a bad idea?) - maybe this is even more secure... Would you like to write an answer yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just disable comments and registration?

This comes to mind also:

(Redirect all requests to login page or admin pages to homepage. A little irreversible.)

```
$currentURL = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if (strpos($currentURL, 'wp-admin' ) or  strpos($currentURL, 'wp-login' )) {
                    header( 'Location: '.site_url() );
}
```

Caution: this stops you from logging in also.

Edit:

And adaptation of the above code put into plugin format can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/5992742). Thanks to brasofilo.

Modified code:

```
add_action( 'init', function()
{
    $currentURL = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if( strpos( $currentURL, 'wp-admin' ) or strpos( $currentURL, 'wp-login' ) )
        exit( wp_redirect( site_url() ) );
} );
```

Comment: sounds interesting - where would I put that?

Comment: You can throw this into the very bottom of your functions.php file of your theme. Like I said tho, this will totally prevent you from logging in to edit anything ever. So you would have to FTP into your server and edit your functions.php to regain access in the future (Or cause wordpress to change the theme).

Comment: thank you for the warning, but in fact disabling posts, comments and the backend is probably one of the best ways to prevent hacks. Requiring ftp access is something every page needed, when the internet was still static ;-)

Comment: A [Must Use](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) plugin is the earliest place to put this code. @Ronburgundy, ain't your example doing a loop? I guess a simple `site_url()` does the job, no?

Comment: @Marcel, I wrote down a [mini-plugin](https://gist.github.com/brasofilo/5992742) adapting Ronburgundy's code. With fast tests, it works ok. Ron, feel free to add it to your Q.

Comment: @brasofilo Answer! Answer! This should be an ... _Answer_! :)

Comment: A plugin would probably be a better place for this. And yes site_url() would probably be best. I sometimes look to avoid wp functions and use straight php when I want to be sure an action is going to occur. I have had trouble with wp_redirect() not functioning as expected in the past so I chose to avoid it in this case. But it does suite here. Bras, if your referring to the lack of the use of exit; after header(), I was / am not aware that it was necessary, but i am aware that its required after wp_redirect.

Comment: @Ronburgundy Hint: Never use anonymous functions in WP. They're a pain in callback hell and nearly impossible to debug as you'll never find them. Always use a real callback.