# Deny a user role to log in after register

Tags: login, user-roles

I have a site where customers can register themselves (they get a user role "pending"). However, what i want is that after this registering these user role cannot automatically log in or log out directly. They must also not be able to log in. Login must therefore be denied for these user role.

Comment: follow these https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66093/how-to-prevent-access-to-wp-admin-for-certain-user-roles

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/

Comment: I don't think that's what I need. I have the user roles already set. Only for the user role "pending" I want this when a new account is getting created (by a front page form) not logged in automatically or logged out direct, and also he can not log in.

I as admin change this new account "pending" to "customer". With the user role "customer", the customer now can login and look at the pages that I have assigned to this user role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is hook into the `authenticate` hook, check if the user has the `pending` role, and if so, throw an error.

```
//* Add filter to the authenticate hook
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'wpse_263762_authenticate', 20, 3 );
function wpse_263762_authenticate( $user, $username, $password ) {
  //* Check if the user has the pending role
  if( ! is_wp_error( $user ) && in_array( 'pending', $user->roles ) ) {
    //* Throw an error
    $error = new WP_Error();
    $errorMessage = __( 'Your error message goes here.' );
    $error->add( 401, $errorMessage );
    return $error;
  }
  //* Or return the user
  return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only i tested it, and it looks the code don't work. I also get the error now on the wp-admin login page: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in www.mysite.com on line 201

Comment: If $user is a WP_User object, then it should have a roles property that is an array (since WP 2.0.0). I've added a check to make sure that $user isn't a WP_Error object.

Comment: It looks like this is it! My cup of soup. Thanks Nathan!!!